# Prove that a finite field with an odd number of elements cannot have 1+1=0.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

All I've been able to deduce is that I should suppose $1+1=0$ in $F$ and then $a+a=0$ for all $a$ in $F$, i.e each element in our field is it's own inverse. And somehow, this is supposed to be impossible because there are an odd number of elements.

I'd like some help with the last part, thanks.

We've done pretty much nothing besides the axioms defining a field, and some other basic things (no zero divisors, cancellation etc)

Edit : My instructor told me (as a hint) to consider the the map $f : a -> a^2$, and then derive a contradiction using the fact that $|F| = odd$. I still don't see a way to get the contradiction.. One (perhaps) useful thing I've noted is that $f$ is a bijection, so we essentially get a copy of the same field with the map.

Comment: Reading your comment below the given \answer, you better write **explicitly** in your question what have you studied and what are you allowed to use to prove what you want...

Answer (score 3):

Let $n$ be the number of elements in the field. Let $S$ be the sum of all elements in the field.

The map $x \mapsto x+1$ is a bijection. (The inverse map is $x \mapsto x-1$.)

Then $S=\sum_x x = \sum_x (x+1) = S+n\cdot1$ and so $n\cdot 1 = 0$.

Write $n = 2q+r$ with $r \in \{0,1\}$. Then
$$
0 = n\cdot 1 = 2q \cdot 1 + r \cdot 1 = r \cdot 1
$$
If $r=1$, then $1=0$ and $n=1$. Otherwise, $r=0$ and $n$ is even.

Comment: Why is S = S + n? Also, why is that map a bijection? Could you perhaps show how to do it using the map $f: a -> a^2$? Thank you

Comment: @John, see my edited answer for the first two points.

Comment: Thanks. Lastly, why is $2q.1 =0$, and how do we n, 2q, r are actually in our field? If they aren't, then does this still make sense?

Comment: @John, $2q \cdot 1 = (1 + 1) + \cdots + (1+1)$, $q$ groups.

Comment: Is there any way I could make this clearer? We seem to be implicitly switching between the field of real numbers and our actual field..

Comment: @John, by definition, $ n \cdot 1 = 1 + 1 + \cdots 1$, $n$ terms. This does not make $n$ an element of the field.